# How do I make an abstract 3D waveform-deformed surface?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I really like this 3D waveform-like approach for this logotype, and I want to create a mesh something like that. Any thoughts/tutorials/approaches I could use?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

Proportional Edit of a moderately high density Cylinder with less extreme shape.  No Caps. Top extruded with loop cuts.  Consider Layers of these types of shapes.

[image]
Multiple Meshes.  Curve Deform and Proportional Edit.

Answer (score 12):

This can be done using a **[Displace](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/deform/displace.html)** modifier.

[image]

- Add a sphere.
- Add a **Displace** modifier.
- Create a new texture for it.
- Choose the texture type "Distorted noise" and play with the options to get something you like.
- Copy the **Displace** modifier and change the *Strength* and *Midlevel* for more sharper edges.
- Add a **Subdivision Surface** modifier and set type of subdivision to *Catmull-Clark* (default).

[image: Modifiers]

[image: Texture]

Answer (score 6):

I have a different method, and I think it will give you a better sense of control, but it will take some experimenting.

1. Add a Mesh >> Circle.
2. Tab into edit mode.
3. <kbd>F</kbd> to fill.
4. <kbd>i</kbd> to inset (Set amount to something like 0.1).
5. Repeat 7 times (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>).
6. Now with the center ring selected turn on proportional editing and set the mode to random.
7. Pull the inner ring downward on Z (Adjust the strength with the scroll wheel on the mouse as desired.
8. change your proportional type to something like sphere or root, and scale, rotate, etc... (Have Fun).

**NOTE:**

On every one of these I applied a SubSurf Modifier, so if you are not getting similar results, it's because I left it out of the steps above. But you can add it at any time.

[image]